# Ограничить ввод текста в ячейку DataGridView определённым набором символов

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли ограничить ввод текста в ячейку (либо во все ячейки) DataGridView определённым набором символов?

Например, чтобы можно было вводить только буквы [a-z], цифры [0-9] и знаки "-" и "/".

Comment: [DataGridView.CellValidating Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [UserName](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3644/username) за подсказку. Желаемого эффекта можно добиться через событие DataGridView.CellValidating и использование регулярных выражений.

Код:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        const string disallowed = @"[^0-9A-Za-z-\/]";
        var newText = Regex.Replace(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), disallowed, string.Empty);
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "";
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) return;
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), newText) == 0) return;
        e.Cancel = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Некорректный символ!";
    }
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]